# Optional relation between two model objects in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two objects A and B in my Rails model which have an optional one-to-one relationship. Say, A can have 0 or 1 B. In most cases A has 0 Bs.

Also, other such relationships can be introduced between A and other objects X, Y, Z later.

Given that these are one-to-one relations, a has-a relationship between A and B makes sense. But given that it is an optional and infrequent relationship, and also that other such relationships can be introduced later with A, adding a new column for each new relationship seems questionable.

How can I model this relationship better? Should using a correlation table between A and B make better sense in this particular case?

Answer (score 0):

You would add the id of Model A to all the other models, and Model A would has_one for each of them.

Each other would belong_to Model A

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the presented solution, that is adding a new column `b_id` to `A`.

Else you could create a third model C which holds both `a_id` and `b_id` and then have `A` access `B` through `C`.

```
# Pluralization is off here. Remember to pluralize has_many
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :c
  has_many :b, through: :c
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :c
  has_many :a, through: :c
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  belongs_to :b
end
```

This would prevent any null values in the database. This is the solution I use most often when I will build something around the relation, since now you have a place to store more information about the relation.

You could also make C polymorphic so that it can store any model (not only A). http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations